# VB.NET - [HTTP POST] Response.Cookies is only returning first cookie value

Tags: .net, vb.net, cookies

I'm using the following code to loop throught the response cookies and save them in a cookiejar.

```
    For Each tempCookie As Cookie In Response.Cookies
        CookieJar.Add(tempCookie)
        MsgBox(tempCookie.ToString)
    Next
```

It happens that it's only returning one cookie, the first one (only runs once in the for):

```
 PAGE_VIS=A|186.213.98.144|1381089446.485193|
```

Response.Cookies has only one cookie on it, but Response.Headers has all of them.
How could I parse them from the Response.Headers and add the on cookiecontainer to use them later?
The cookies in Response.Headers are here:

```
Set-Cookie: PAGE_VIS=A|186.213.98.144|1381089446.485193|; domain=PAGE; path=/; expires=Mon, 07-Oct-2013 06:00:00 GMT,CSASF=;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=7776000,CSAPAGES=ekpEOWluWTZSMXpDSWRMMm8wWWZ3UT09|5749|kNm6h4hlOB4SwLFg2gOIMXXpmTXDD5tnvB/dJ7AS3mUqUiLtpHLxzsWjfKsI1rcq6fp/DKre3QHAZHPQi968iw==;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=7776000;HttpOnly,NAM_LOGIN_DEFAULT=user;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=129600,UPL09=2-25|39|54|56|58|90|91|105|106|156|182|212|218|219|242|245|248|284|285|480|1222;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=2592000,PAGE_OTR=;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=2592000,CAUBR01=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;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/
```

Why it isn't getting all the rest of the cookies, only the first one?
How do I solve that?

The entire function in here:

```
Private Function LogonPage(ByVal URL As String, ByRef CookieJar As CookieContainer, ByVal PostData As String)
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)

    Request.Method = "POST"
    Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14"
    Request.CookieContainer = CookieJar
    Request.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Request.ContentLength = PostData.Length

    Dim requestStream As Stream = Request.GetRequestStream()
    Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData)

    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

    For Each tempCookie As Cookie In Response.Cookies
        CookieJar.Add(tempCookie)
    Next

    reader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
    Return reader.ReadToEnd()
    Response.Close()
End Function
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong, and if it's possible, point me to the solution?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of multiple cookies, `Set-Cookie` header might contain cookies separated by comma `,` while cookie properties are separated by semicolon `;` and `Response.Headers("Set-Cookie")` returns all cookies in a `string`.

1. Apply cookie separation technique on `Response.Headers("Set-Cookie")`
2. Extract each cookie's *name, value, path, domain etc.*
3. Create `Cookie` objects with this information
4. Add cookies to `CookieContainer`.

Note that splitting cookies on comma `,` is not useful because any cookie property like *expires* might also contain comma in it like *expires=Mon, 07-Oct-2013 06:00:00 GMT*:

```
Dim strCookies As String = Response.Headers("Set-Cookie")

' Splitting on comma is just for example
Dim cookies() As String = strCookies.Split(commaDelimeter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For Each ck As String In cookies
    Dim ckProp() As String = ck.Split(semicolonDelimeter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim cookie As New Cookie(ckProp(0), ckProp(1))
    CookieJar.Add(cookie)        
Next ck
```

Comment: It's more complex than I tought, the only way to parse it properly would be using regex I guess :c

Comment: Also, why Response.Cookies it's not getting all of them?

Comment: Yes you can use Regex, not sure why it behaves in this way.